# Compile type mismatch when using getClass() with some complicated Java generics

Tags: java, generics

I have a method with this interface:

```
public <A extends Message, B extends Message> MessageConverter<A, B>
    getDefaultConverterFor(Class<A> inputClass, Class<B> outputClass);
```

where the idea is that you have an Message of type A that you want to convert into an Message of type B, and you want to get a converter to do that from a repository of registered converters available. Unfortunately, I'm having huge trouble getting the types at either end of this to work as I expect.

More specifically, I'm trying to do this:

```
public <M extends Message> Message convert(M m)
{
    MessageConverter<M, DictMessage> converter = 
        getDefaultConverterFor(m.getClass(), DictMessage.class);

    return converter.convert(m);                
}
```

(i.e. take a message of any type and convert it into a DictMessage) but it gives me a compile error on the getDefaultConverter line:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from MessageConverter<capture#1-of ? extends Message,DictMessage> to MessageConverter<Message,DictMessage>".
```

I'm not even sure why this happens, let alone how to fix it. I'd imagine it's something to do with the class returned by getClass not quite matching up with M, but I don't really know. I could believe that it's possible that this is something that actually just doesn't work, but I can't think of any particular examples that break it... Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a problem with Object.getClass() returning `Class<?>` for some time.  The compiler doesn't know that `m.getClass()` is `Class<M>` but you can fix that with a cast.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
MessageConverter<M, DictMessage> converter =
        getDefaultConverterFor((Class<M>) m.getClass(), DictMessage.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public <M extends Message> Message convert(M m) {
  Class<M> abc = m.getClass(); // compile error
  ...
}
```

does not work.

You can add a type cast before the `getClass()` call.

```
public <M extends Message> Message convert(M m) {
  Class<M> abc = (class<M>)m.getClass(); // ok
  ...
}
```

Or you can add an additional class parameter to your method:

```
public <M extends Message> Message convert(M m, Class<M> mClass) {
  // use mClass instead of m.getClass()
  ...
}
```

Or you can change the type parameter of your `MessageConverter` variable:

```
public <M extends Message> Message convert(M m) {
  MessageConverter<? extends Message, DictMessage> converter = this.getDefaultConverterFor(m.getClass(), DictMessage.class);
```

Javadoc for `getClass()` return value says:

```
The java.lang.Class object that represents the runtime class of the object. 
The result is of type Class<? extends X> where X is the erasure of the static 
type of the expression on which getClass is called.
```

So the return type of `getClass()` in your case is `Class<? extends Message>` and not `Class<Message>`.

Answer (score 1):

The following is fully typed.

```
public class MessageConverter<INP extends Message, OUTP extends Message> {
    private Class<INP> inputClass;
    private Class<OUTP> outputClass;

    public MessageConverter(Class<INP> inputClass, Class<OUTP> outputClass) {
        this.inputClass = inputClass;
        this.outputClass = outputClass;
    }

    public OUTP convert(INP m) {
        try {
            return outputClass.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public <INP extends Message, OUTP extends Message> MessageConverter<INP, OUTP>
        getDefaultConverterFor(Class<INP> inputClass, Class<OUTP> outputClass) {
    MessageConverter<INP, OUTP> mc = new MessageConverter<INP, OUTP>(inputClass, outputClass);
    return mc;
}

public <INP extends Message> MessageConverter<INP, DictMessage>
        getDictConverterFor(Class<INP> inputClass) {
    MessageConverter<INP, DictMessage> mc =
            new MessageConverter<INP, DictMessage>(inputClass, DictMessage.class);
    return mc;
}
```